# how to replace explicit wait calls in cypress?

Tags: wait, cypress

I am facing several situations where an element can't be clicked using `cy.get().click()` just because the elements have not loaded. However, if i add even the smallest of waits like `cy.wait(100);` the elements become clickable and my code runs fine.

Can this practice of explicitly calling `cy.wait()` be avoided?

I think if I can somehow set a fixed wait of `cy.wait(100)` i.e 0.1ms between all the steps my issue would be addressed but I don't know how to do it.
[image]

Comment: Yes, using `cy.wait(100)` in that fashion is bad practice and you can and should avoid it. Check out https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Unnecessary-Waiting. Read that entire section for your answer with a specific focus on the part there about `cy.get`. Hope that helps.

Comment: The approach should be to wait for the content that is loading, e.g `cy.contains(selector, content).click()`. This will retry until loading is completed. Assumes that loading results in a visible change on the page. Please post some code for a more exact answer.

Comment: @eric99 i am using this command `cy.get('.ant-btn').click()` and if my page takes a bit longer to load, 5 elements are located from this command instead of a unique element. If i add cy.wait(100) before the above-mentioned get command, the desired element is clicked. i am adding the error screenshot in the question as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution to this, posting it for others to use later

```
 cy.get('<your-selector-here>').should('be.visible').then(   ($el)  =>  {   $el.click() }    )
```

you can simply use this assertion `.should('be.visible')` to replace the explicit wait calls.

However, there's a catch to it; this only works for the cases where you're 100% sure that the element would appear. If the element does not appear, the assertion will simply fail and the test won't continue further.

Answer (score 0):

One Solution is, you can use
Cypress.config(defaultCommandTimeout: 10000) to increase default command time out for the specific situation.
This increased time out will work for all the lines, after the execution of this code.